# Exporting shape keys animation to .dae

Tags: animation, shape-keys, collada

Is there a way to do it? When I chech "export shape keys" and reimport the file after the export there's no animation or keyframes but the shape keys are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php?title=Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import/COLLADA#COLLADA_Import_and_Export_.282.79.29) it doesn't look like this is possible (at least as of  Blender version 2.79).

At the very bottom of that page:

**Important things to remember**

- only armature animation on mesh, single skin controller

I read that to mean it isn't possible to export shape key animations to .dae from Blender at this time.